# Как работает союз "и (или)"?

Tags: союзы, и, или

Есть такое выражение: "Организация, не отнесенная к категории по гражданской обороне и (или) прекращающая работу в военное время". Как здесь работает связка *и (или)*? Равнозначны ли союзы "и" и "или", если союз "или" стоит в скобках - как в тексте выше? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Здесь охватываются сразу *два* вида организаций (или условий/критериев, применяемых к рассматриваемой организации):

1. "не отнесённые" и при этом "прекращающие" и
2. "отнесённые", но "прекращающие".

Союз "и" объединяет два условия, выполняемые одновременно, а союз "или" *приравнивает* этому случаю (с точки зрения рассматриваемого статуса организации) выполнение только второго условия.

Comment: Формально Вы правы: именно так надо понимать этот текст. Но давайте задумаемся. По сути, все определяет лишь один фактор: прекращает ли организация работу в военное время. Зачем это дополнительные логические навороты про гражданскую оборону?

Answer (score 0):

Лично я склонен рассматривать связку "и/или" как логическое "конъюнкция/дизъюнкция", (также "[штрих Шеффера и стрелка Пирса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8#%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B_%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9)"),
а потому:
"и" истина - совокупное выполнение условий
"или" истина - выполнение одного из условий
"и/не" истина - совокупное отсутствие условий
"или/не" истина - отсутствие одного из условий
Если мы напишем "и" - возникнет неопределённость при выполнении одного из условий.
Если напишем "или" - возникнет неопределённость при совокупном выполнении условий.
Отсюда и появилась потребность в связке "и/или".
И я не думаю, что взятие в скобки одного из этих элементов должно хоть как-то  "умалять его достоинство".